# Keeps getting garbage values when doing merge sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I am working on a generic merge sort algorithm. Now the problem is I keep getting garbage values when I print the content of the supposedly "sorted" array.

The merge sort algorithm:

```
void merge(void *a, int n, int size, int (*fcmp)(const void *, const void *)){
    int i, j, k, mid=n/2;
    void * temp = (void *)malloc(n*size);

    for(i=0, j=mid, k=0; k<n; k++){
        if((i<mid)&&(j>=  n)){
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+i*size, size);
            i++;
        }
        else if((i<mid)&&(fcmp(a + i*size, a+j*size) <= 0)){
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+j*size, size);
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0, j=0; j<n; i++, j++)
        memcpy(a+(j*size),temp+(i*size),size);
    free(temp);
}

void genmsort(void *a, int n, int size, int (*fcmp)(const void *, const void *)){
    if(n>1){
        genmsort(a, n/2, size, (int(*)(const void *, const void *)) compnode);
        genmsort(a+(n/2)*size, n-n/2, size, (int(*)(const void *, const void *)) compnode);
        merge(a, n, size, (int(*)(const void *, const void *)) compnode);
    }
}
```

The compnode function:

```
int compnode(node *a, node *b){
    return (strcmp(a->name, b->name));
}
```

The initialization function:

```
void init_node(node a[], int n){
int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i].stdno=i+1;
        sprintf(a[i].name, "%li", a[i].stdno);
    }
    srand(8);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        genswap(a+i, a+(rand()%n), sizeof(node));
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main(){
    int n=10;
    clock_t t1, t2;

    node *b;
    b=(node *)malloc(n*sizeof(node));
    init_node(b, n);

    t1=clock();
    genmsort(b, n, sizeof(node), (int(*)(const void *, const void *)) compnode);

    t2=clock();
    free(b);
}
```

What could be wrong here? I'm sorry for the lengthy code but I hope you can understand it. I would really appreciate your help because I am stuck with this code for some time now.

Comment: For pity's sake, write `compnode()` sanely so that you don't have to go through the ghastly casts!  Write it to take two `const void *` arguments and convert them in the code (it'll be a no-op): `int compnode(const void *v1, const void *v2) { const node *a = v1; const node *b = v2; return strcmp(a->name, b->name); }`!

Comment: Also, don't use GCC's extensions.  It is a bad habit.  Writing `a+(n/2)*size` where the argument is `void *a` is undefined behaviour per the C standard.  You have to convert to `char *` (or some other type other than `void *`) before adding.

Comment: In `genmnode()`, you should be passing `fcmp` to the recursive functions and the `merge()` function, instead of passing `compnode` directly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What do you mean pass fcmp instead of compnode?

Comment: @Gannicus he means you're passing your custom comparator function to the "generic" sort function as the `fcmp` parameter. Within that function, you blindly pass `compnode` to the recursive calls. You should be passing `fcmp` to those recursive calls instead, or your "generic" ideology just went out the window.

Comment: @WhozCraig I changed the compnode call into fcmp but I still get the same wrong output.

Comment: The problem is in your `merge()` function.  The interface to that is most unusual.  Normally, you pass two arrays to be merged, along with the size of each.  You've chosen to pass one array and do some fancy footwork.  The code in the main `for` loop in screws everything up — I'm not sure I can be bothered to work out how (it's bedtime here).

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). You almost got bonus points for casting **to** `void *`, that's a new one, but please just don't cast. Don't.

Comment: @unwind casting to `void*`. Thats *awesome*.

Answer (score 2):

#### Auxilliary problems

*Transcribed from the comments to the question.*

For pity's sake, write `compnode()` sanely so that you don't have to go through the ghastly casts! Write it to take two `const void *` arguments and convert them in the code (it'll be a no-op):

```
int compnode(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const node *a = v1;
    const node *b = v2;
    return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}
```

Also, don't use GCC's extensions. It is a bad habit if you have any pretensions towards writing portable code. Writing `a+(n/2)*size` where the argument is `void *a` is undefined behaviour per the C standard. You have to convert to `char *` (or some other type other than `void *`) before adding.

In `genmnode()`, you should be passing `fcmp` to the recursive functions and the `merge()` function, instead of passing `compnode()` directly.

[Gannicus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743334/gannicus) asked:

> What do you mean pass `fcmp` instead of `compnode`?

[WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) explained:

> [It] means you're passing your custom comparator function to the "generic" sort function as the `fcmp` parameter. Within that function, you blindly pass `compnode` to the recursive calls. You should be passing `fcmp` to those recursive calls instead, or your "generic" ideology just went out the window.

#### Primary problem

The primary problem is in your `merge()` function. The interface to that is most unusual. Normally, you pass two arrays to be merged, along with the size of each. You've chosen to pass one array and do some fancy footwork. The code in the main for loop in screws everything up.

```
void merge(void *a, int n, int size, int (*fcmp)(const void *, const void *)){
    int i, j, k, mid=n/2;
    void * temp = (void *)malloc(n*size);

    for(i=0, j=mid, k=0; k<n; k++){
        if((i<mid)&&(j>=  n)){
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+i*size, size);
            i++;
        }
        else if((i<mid)&&(fcmp(a + i*size, a+j*size) <= 0)){
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+j*size, size);
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0, j=0; j<n; i++, j++)
        memcpy(a+(j*size),temp+(i*size),size);
    free(temp);
}
```

The trailing loop should be a single `memcpy()` operation, but what's there will work.

You have a single array, `a`, with a total of `n` elements of the given size.  It must be treated as two sub-arrays, one of elements [0..mid), the LHS, and the other of elements [mid..n), the RHS. The ranges include the lower bound and exclude the upper bound.

The first condition inside the loop says 'if there is an element left in LHS and nothing left in RHS, copy the LHS element to the output'.  The second condition says 'if there is an element left in the LHS (and, by elimination, there is an element in the RHS too), and the LHS compares smaller than the RHS, then copy the RHS element to the output'.

There are different and ultimately equivalent ways to write the merge process, but 
normally the easiest to understand is:

```
while (item left in LHS and item left in RHS)
{
    if (item in LHS is smaller than item in RHS)
        copy LHS to result
    else
        copy RHS to result
}
while (item left in LHS)
    copy item to result
while (item left in RHS)
    copy item to result
```

The loop implemented does not come close to implementing that logic, or one of its equivalents.

---

#### Working code

Here's my diagnostic version of your code.  The `memset()` at the top of `merge()` should not matter; you should be copying to `temp` and writing over all the X's.  In practice, you are not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node node;
struct node
{
    long stdno;
    char name[20];
};

static
void genswap(void *v1, void *v2, size_t size)
{
    char v3[size];
    memmove(v3, v1, size);
    memmove(v1, v2, size);
    memmove(v2, v3, size);
}

static
void print_node(const char *tag, node a[], int n)
{
    printf("%s\n", tag);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%2d: %p %2ld %s\n", i, &a[i], a[i].stdno, a[i].name);
}

static
void merge(void *a, int n, int size, int (*fcmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    int i, j, k, mid = n/2;
    void *temp = (void *)malloc(n*size);
    memset(temp, 'X', n*size);

    printf("-->> %s\n", __func__);
    print_node("Before Merge", (node *)a, n);
    for (i = 0, j = mid, k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        if ((i < mid) && (j >= n))
        {
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+i*size, size);
            i++;
        }
        else if ((i < mid) && (fcmp(a + i*size, a+j*size) <= 0))
        {
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+j*size, size);
            j++;
        }
    }
    print_node("Mid Merge", (node *)temp, n);

    for (i = 0, j = 0; j < n; i++, j++)
        memcpy(a+(j*size), temp+(i*size), size);
    free(temp);
    print_node("After Merge", (node *)a, n);
    printf("<<-- %s\n", __func__);
}

static
void genmsort(void *a, int n, int size, int (*fcmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        genmsort(a, n/2, size, fcmp);
        genmsort(a+(n/2)*size, n-n/2, size, fcmp);
        merge(a, n, size, fcmp);
    }
}

static
int compnode(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const node *a = v1;
    const node *b = v2;
    printf("%s: (%ld:%s) vs (%ld:%s)\n", __func__, a->stdno, a->name, b->stdno, b->name);
    return(strcmp(a->name, b->name));
}

static
void init_node(node a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i].stdno = i+1;
        sprintf(a[i].name, "%li", a[i].stdno);
    }
    srand(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        genswap(a+i, a+(rand()%n), sizeof(node));
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 10;
    node *b = (node *)malloc(n*sizeof(node));

    init_node(b, n);
    print_node("Before:", b, n);
    genmsort(b, n, sizeof(node), compnode);
    print_node("After:", b, n);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The latitude of things in this code are copious. Some are show-stoppers, but ultimately it is your merge function. A typical merge algorithm moves ***one*** item into the target buffer with each iteration until such time as one list or the other is exhausted. Once that happens the remaining items in the remaining list are bulk-copied into place and the algorithm terminates.

You have a fundamental flaw, and we'll cover that now. Your main loop runs `k` all the way through to `n`, and at least that is right. But, look at your first expressions in your if-else-if conditions:

```
    if((i<mid)&&(j>=  n))
    {
        memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+i*size, size);
        i++;
    }
    else if((i<mid)&&(fcmp(a + i*size, a+j*size) <= 0))
    {
        memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+j*size, size);
        j++;
    }
```

They *both* have `i<mid`, so this could be simplified to be:

```
    if (i<mid)
    {
        if (j>=n)
        {
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+i*size, size);
            i++;
        }
        else if (fcmp(a + i*size, a+j*size) <= 0))
        {
            memcpy(temp+(k*size), a+j*size, size);
            j++;
        }
    }
```

which means if your `i`-side is *ever* exhausted before your `j`-side, you simply do *nothing* from that point on, just incrementing `k` until it reaches `n`. The rest of the `j`-side of the split-list is completely ignored. Then, at the end of the function you copy uninitialized data right over the top of your original array.

Some things to consider. First,  typedef your comparator function requirements and stick to it. It is the responsibility of the comparator to adhere to the requirements of the callback-requestor; not the other way around.

```
typedef int (*fn_cmp)(const void*, const void*);
```

and use this *correctly* by implementing your callback to that standard.

```
// compare two nodes.
int compare_node(const void* lhs, const void* rhs)
{
    const node* lhn = lhs;
    const node* rhn = rhs;
    return (strcmp(lhn->name, rhn->name));
}
```

This also makes your generic mergesort *much* cleaner:

```
// generic mergesort algorithm
void genmsort(void *src, unsigned int len, unsigned int size, fn_cmp fcmp)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    unsigned int mid = len/2;
    genmsort(src, mid, size, fcmp);
    genmsort((unsigned char*)src+(mid*size), len - mid, size, fcmp);
    merge(src, mid, len-mid, size, fcmp);
}
```

Readability aside, the biggest difference between the following `merge` and yours is the addition of the second length parameter (the fact that this one *works* is considered a bonus). You're code inferred this value from the single length originally passed in; something you did in an entirely separate place in your code when calculating your recursive partition sizes Those same sizes need to be passed here as well, for multiple reasons that include consistency and usability).

Consider the following *please*. If it is possible to annotate this algorithm better, or make it clearer, I'm at a loss to see how:

```
// merges two lists back to back in a single sequence.
void merge(void *src,
           unsigned int alen, // note parition size.
           unsigned int blen, // and again here.
           unsigned int size,
           fn_cmp fcmp)
{
    void *bsrc = (unsigned char*)src + alen * size;
    void *dst = malloc((alen + blen)*size);
    unsigned int a = 0, b = 0, k = 0;

    for (k=0; k<(alen+blen); ++k)
    {
        // still got a's ?
        if (a < alen)
        {
            // still got b's ?
            if (b < blen)
            {
                // get "lesser" of the two.
                if (fcmp((const unsigned char*)src + a*size,
                         (const unsigned char*)bsrc + b*size) <= 0)
                {
                    // a is less. move it in.
                    memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                           (const unsigned char*)src + a++*size, size);
                }
                else
                {   // b is less. move it in.
                    memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                           (const unsigned char*)bsrc + b++*size, size);
                }
            }
            else
            {   // no more b's. move the rest of the a's
                // into the target and leave.
                memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                       (const unsigned char*)src + a*size, (alen - a)*size);
                k += (alen-a);
            }
        }
        else
        {   // else no a's. move the rest of the b's into
            //  the target and leave.
            memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                   (const unsigned char*)bsrc + b*size, (blen - b)*size);
            k += (blen-b);
        }
    }

    // copy final output.
    memcpy(src, dst, (alen+blen)*size);
    free(dst);
}
```

Finally, this codes does *not* require any compiler extensions such as the standard-violating incremental `void*` you so-heavily exploited in your code. I *strongly* advise you stay clear of such extensions.

---

The following is the full test program used to verify the algorithm above and its interface. Read it *carefully*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

// simple node definition.
typedef struct node
{
    char name[32];
    int id;
} node;

// compare two nodes.
int compare_node_names(const void* lhs, const void* rhs)
{
    const node* lhn = lhs;
    const node* rhn = rhs;
    return (strcmp(lhn->name, rhn->name));
}

// compare two nodes.
int compare_node_ids(const void* lhs, const void* rhs)
{
    const node* lhn = lhs;
    const node* rhn = rhs;
    return (lhn->id  - rhn->id);
}

// comparator requirements.
typedef int (*fn_cmp)(const void*, const void*);

// merges two lists back to back in a single sequence.
void merge(void *src,
           unsigned int alen, // note parition size.
           unsigned int blen, // and again here.
           unsigned int size,
           fn_cmp fcmp)
{
    void *bsrc = (unsigned char*)src + alen * size;
    void *dst = malloc((alen + blen)*size);
    unsigned int a = 0, b = 0, k = 0;

    for (k=0; k<(alen+blen); ++k)
    {
        // still got a's ?
        if (a < alen)
        {
            // still got b's ?
            if (b < blen)
            {
                // get "lesser" of the two.
                if (fcmp((const unsigned char*)src + a*size,
                         (const unsigned char*)bsrc + b*size) <= 0)
                {
                    // a is less. move it in.
                    memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                           (const unsigned char*)src + a++*size, size);
                }
                else
                {   // b is less. move it in.
                    memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                           (const unsigned char*)bsrc + b++*size, size);
                }
            }
            else
            {   // no more b's. move the rest of the a's
                // into the target and leave.
                memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                       (const unsigned char*)src + a*size, (alen - a)*size);
                k += (alen-a);
            }
        }
        else
        {   // else no a's. move the rest of the b's into
            //  the target and leave.
            memcpy((unsigned char *)dst + k*size,
                   (const unsigned char*)bsrc + b*size, (blen - b)*size);
            k += (blen-b);
        }
    }

    // copy final output.
    memcpy(src, dst, (alen+blen)*size);
    free(dst);
}

// generic mergesort algorithm
void genmsort(void *src, unsigned int len, unsigned int size, fn_cmp fcmp)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    unsigned int mid = len/2;
    genmsort(src, mid, size, fcmp);
    genmsort((unsigned char*)src+(mid*size), len - mid, size, fcmp);
    merge(src, mid, len-mid, size, fcmp);
}

int main()
{
    static const unsigned int N = 50;
    node *data = malloc(N * sizeof(*data));
    int i=0;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        data[i].id = i+1;
        sprintf(data[i].name, "String%.3d", 1 + rand() % 999);
    }

    // sort on names.
    genmsort(data, N, sizeof(data[0]), compare_node_names);
    for (i=0;i<N;++i)
        printf("%s : %u\n", data[i].name, data[i].id);
    printf("\n");

    // use a different comparator, this time by id.
    genmsort(data, N, sizeof(data[0]), compare_node_ids);
    for (i=0;i<N;++i)
        printf("%s : %u\n", data[i].name, data[i].id);
    printf("\n");

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
String053 : 49
String097 : 38
String104 : 46
String122 : 41
String129 : 8
String139 : 3
String168 : 30
String184 : 22
String222 : 16
String230 : 28
String249 : 4
String265 : 34
String285 : 44
String295 : 20
String298 : 47
String300 : 19
String321 : 2
String375 : 37
String396 : 50
String408 : 13
String430 : 31
String466 : 35
String483 : 24
String484 : 27
String491 : 25
String494 : 39
String507 : 10
String513 : 7
String514 : 11
String539 : 5
String556 : 29
String570 : 43
String583 : 33
String584 : 42
String620 : 15
String632 : 12
String671 : 21
String705 : 23
String710 : 14
String714 : 45
String724 : 18
String733 : 9
String755 : 48
String805 : 36
String814 : 6
String847 : 32
String876 : 40
String893 : 26
String906 : 17
String972 : 1

String972 : 1
String321 : 2
String139 : 3
String249 : 4
String539 : 5
String814 : 6
String513 : 7
String129 : 8
String733 : 9
String507 : 10
String514 : 11
String632 : 12
String408 : 13
String710 : 14
String620 : 15
String222 : 16
String906 : 17
String724 : 18
String300 : 19
String295 : 20
String671 : 21
String184 : 22
String705 : 23
String483 : 24
String491 : 25
String893 : 26
String484 : 27
String230 : 28
String556 : 29
String168 : 30
String430 : 31
String847 : 32
String583 : 33
String265 : 34
String466 : 35
String805 : 36
String375 : 37
String097 : 38
String494 : 39
String876 : 40
String122 : 41
String584 : 42
String570 : 43
String285 : 44
String714 : 45
String104 : 46
String298 : 47
String755 : 48
String053 : 49
String396 : 50
```